# Using Python3 in Datalab, I can't feed a list of strings which represent files in a Google Cloud Storage bucket as a feed_dict with tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform

I am new to tf and I have a problem where I am trying to process some files.  Here is a excerpt of code.

```
xlabel_to_files_list_map['dog_bark'] # subset of data with two files

# result
['gs://some_bucket/some_dir/data/dog_bark/100652.mp3', 'gs://some_bucket/some_dir/dog_bark/100795.mp3']
```

Here is where I am simply trying to get these strings to be processed by a simple graph:

```
file_to_process = tf.placeholder(tf.string)

audio_binary_remote = tf.gfile.Open(file_to_process, 'rb').read()

waveform = tf.contrib.ffmpeg.decode_audio(audio_binary_remote, file_format='mp3', samples_per_second=44100, channel_count=2)


with tf.Session() as sess:
 result = sess.run(waveform, feed_dict={
 file_to_process: xlabel_to_files_list_map['dog_bark']
 })
#print (result)
```

This results in

```
TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_9:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=string>
```

FWIW, this works

```
a_string = tf.placeholder(tf.string) 
z = a_string 
with tf.Session() as sess: 
    result = sess.run(z, feed_dict={a_string: ['one', 'two', 'three']}) 
print(result)
```

This results in

```
['one' 'two' 'three']
```

The simple example which works is of a list of strings.  The more complex example which uses a hash map value part which is a list of strings.  I'm not sure why it doesn't work similar to the second example.

**Another Approach**

I tried to do this another way.  This time I tried to build a list of results and then process the list.  This also failed.  It did not produce an error.  It simply gave blank results.

```
waveform_tensor_list = []
for a_file in dir_to_selected_files_list_map['gs://some_bucket/some_dir/dog_bark/']:
  #print (a_file)
  waveform = tf.contrib.ffmpeg.decode_audio(a_file, file_format='mp3', samples_per_second=44100, channel_count=2)
  waveform_tensor_list.append(waveform)
```

The output from this cell looks wrong immediately but in the proper form:

```
waveform_tensor_list
```

resulting in:

```
[<tf.Tensor 'DecodeAudioV2_7:0' shape=(?, 2) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'DecodeAudioV2_8:0' shape=(?, 2) dtype=float32>,
 stuff deleted,
 <tf.Tensor 'DecodeAudioV2_22:0' shape=(?, 2) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'DecodeAudioV2_23:0' shape=(?, 2) dtype=float32>]
```

Then to evaluate the graph, this:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  result = sess.run(waveform_tensor_list)
  print (result)
```

Where the output from this cell is:

```
[array([], shape=(0, 0), dtype=float32), array([], shape=(0, 0), dtype=float32), array([], shape=(0, 0), dtype=float32), array([], shape=(0, 0), dtype=float32), array([], shape=(0, 0), dtype=float32), array([], shape=(0, 0), dtype=float32), array([], shape=(0, 0), dtype=float32), array([], shape=(0, 0), dtype=float32), array([], shape=(0, 0), dtype=float32), array([], shape=(0, 0), dtype=float32), array([], shape=(0, 0), dtype=float32), array([], shape=(0, 0), dtype=float32), array([], shape=(0, 0), dtype=float32), array([], shape=(0, 0), dtype=float32), array([], shape=(0, 0), dtype=float32), array([], shape=(0, 0), dtype=float32), array([], shape=(0, 0), dtype=float32)]
```

Comment: It appears the code should work from what I've read.  This is a bit of a long shot, but have you tried using str(audio_binary_remote) as the first argument of decode_audio?

Comment: No I had not, but per your suggestion I tried just now.  Sadly it has a similar problem.

Comment: fwiw, I found someone posting a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50940768/tensorflow-typeerror-expected-binary-or-unicode-string-got-tf-tensor-placeh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tf.gfile.Open` isn't a TensorFlow operation. In other words, it does not add operations to the graph to open the file.

`tf.gfile.Open` is an alias for the class [`tf.gfile.GFile`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gfile/GFile). So the line `tf.gfile.Open(<foo>)` is invoking `tf.gfile.GFile.__init__` which expects the first argument to be a Python string, not `tf.Tensor` of strings (which is what `tf.placeholder(tf.string)` returns).

You have a few options here:

#### Feed the contents of the file

```
raw_data = tf.placeholder(tf.string)
waveform = tf.contrib.ffmpeg.decode_audio(raw_data, file_format='mp3', samples_per_second=44100, channel_count=2)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for file in xlabel_to_files_list_map['dog_bark']:
      result = sess.run(waveform, feed_dict={raw_data: tf.gfile.GFile(file, 'rb').read()})
```

#### Open and read the file in the graph

(Using the [`tf.data` classes to setup "input processing"](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets))

```
filenames = xlabel_to_files_list_map['dog_bark']
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames).map(lambda x: tf.read_file(x))

raw_data = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
waveform =  tf.contrib.ffmpeg.decode_audio(raw_data, file_format='mp3', samples_per_second=44100, channel_count=2)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for _ in filenames:
        result = sess.run(waveform)
```

#### Use eager execution

(See the [Research and Experimentation section of the TensorFlow getting started guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/))

Which may help reduce some of the confusion between what's in the graph and what's happening in Python.

```
tf.enable_eager_execution()
for filename in xlabel_to_files_list_map['dog_bark']:
    result = tf.contrib.ffmpeg.decode_audio(tf.gfile.GFile(filename, 'rb').read(), file_format='mp3', samples_per_second=44100, channel_count=2)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Excellent.  I'm new to tensorflow so it will take me a while to digest your answer.  Once, I do, I will respond back here.  Many thanks!

Comment: If you are new to TensorFlow, I'd recommend getting started with eager execution and the resources I mentioned above.

Comment: Using the first method, results in an error.  UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 25: invalid start byte

Comment: Using the second method, also results in an error: TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: Ahh, it was a simple fix given your answer. The fix was to add, a 'rb' in the GFile() line.  I will edit your answer to show that result.

Comment: The same addition for the third approach works as well.  Many thanks!  I could not fix the second approach

Answer (score 1):

I've not used tensor flow, but per the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gfile/GFile) tf.gfile.Open creates a GFile object.  tf.contrib.ffmpeg.decode_audio is expecting a binary out unicode string.  Since GFile does have a read() function I would try using the flowing:

`waveform = tf.contrib.ffmpeg.decode_audio(audio_binary_remote.read(), file_format='mp3', samples_per_second=44100, channel_count=2)`

Comment: Many thanks @MVanOrder.  I appreciate your help, but unfortunately that gives the same error. TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=string>

Comment: I appologize I missed the .read() ad the end of the line where you set audio_binary_remote.

Comment: No worries pal.  Thanks again for the help.